# Stone's duality for atomic Boolean algebras

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory, boolean-algebra

I'm dealing with Stone's representation theorem for finite Boolean algebras, i.e. if $B$ is a finite Boolean algebra and $A$ is the set of its atoms then

\begin{align}
 \phi: B &\to P(A)\\
 b &\mapsto \{a \in A \,.\, a \leq b\}
\end{align}

is a Boolean algebra-isomorphism.

---

For an atomic Boolean algebra $x \leq y$ if and only if $\phi(x) \subseteq \phi(y)$:

the implication $\Rightarrow$ is trivial (transitivity) while the other follows from
$$x = (x \wedge y) \vee (x \wedge (\neg y))$$
and the fact that $x \wedge (\neg y) = 0$, since otherwise we would have an atom $a \leq x \wedge (\neg y)$ therefore $a \leq x$ and $a > y$ against hypotesis, so $x = x \wedge y$ and $x \leq y$.

With that we have

- $\phi$ is *injective* since if $\phi(b_1) = \phi(b_2)$ then $b_1 = \sup(\phi(b_1)) = \sup(\phi(b_2)) = b_2$;

---

**Questions**:

- do I need $B$ to be finite for having that $\phi(\sup(X)) = X$, i.e. $\{a \in A \,.\, a \leq \sup(X)\} \subseteq X$? Or is this theorem true for *atomic* BA?
- I can prove that $\phi$ preserve the structure $(0, 1, \wedge, \vee, \neg)$, but it seems a bit unclean(gosh, at least two equalities!); is it enough if $\phi$ preserve $0$, $1$ and is strictly monic (so it follows from the first observation and injectivity) to be a BA-morphism?

Comment: The Boolean algebra $P(X)$ is complete; so if the atomic algebra $B$ is not complete, it will not be isomorphic to $P(X)$, but it is isomorphic to a subalgebra thereof.

Comment: It's true for atomic and complete BA's. All finite BA's are both.

Comment: and there atomic uncomplete BA's, so I need completeness. What about the other question?

Comment: Concerning the second question, you need to prove that the map preserves $0,1$ and one among $\wedge$ and $\vee$ (any of the two); if you prefer, you can prove that it preserves $\neg$, instead of $0$ and $1$.